# Using FParsec to parse possibly malformed input

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

I'm writing a parser for a specific file format using FParsec as a firstish foaray into learning fsharp. Part of the file has the following format

```
{ 123 456 789 333 }
```

Where the numbers in the brackets are pairs of values and there can be an arbitrary number of spaces to separate them. So these would also be valid things to parse:

```
{  22 456              7 333     }
```

And of course the content of the brackets might be empty, i.e. `{}`

In addition I want the parser to be able to handle the case where the content is a bit malformed, eg. `{ some descriptive text }` or maybe more likely `{ 12 3 4}` (invalid since the `4` wouldn't be paired with anything). In this case I just want the contents saved to be processed separately.

I have this so far:

```
type DimNummer = int
type ObjektNummer = int
type DimObjektPair = DimNummer * ObjektNummer
type ObjektListResult = Result<DimObjektPair list, string>


let sieObjektLista = 
    let pnum = numberLiteral NumberLiteralOptions.None "dimOrObj"
    let ws = spaces
    let pobj = pnum .>> ws |>> fun x -> 
        let on: ObjektNummer = int x.String
        on
    let pdim = pnum |>> fun x -> 
        let dim: DimNummer = int x.String
        dim

    let pdimObj = (pdim .>> spaces1) .>>. pobj |>> DimObjektPair

    let toObjektLista(objList:list<DimObjektPair>) = 
        let res: ObjektListResult = Result.Ok objList
        res

    let pdimObjs = sepBy pdimObj spaces1
    let validList = pdimObjs |>> toObjektLista

    let toInvalid(str:string) = 
        let res: ObjektListResult = 
            match str.Trim(' ')  with 
            | "" -> Result.Ok []
            | _ -> Result.Error str
        res

    let invalidList = manyChars anyChar |>> toInvalid
    let pres = between (pchar '{') (pchar '}') (ws >>. (validList <|> invalidList) .>> ws)
    pres

let parseSieObjektLista = run sieObjektLista
```

However running this on a valid sample I get an error:

```
{ 53735        7785  86231   36732         }
                     ^
Expecting: whitespace or '}'
```

Comment: just a hint: at least for debugging (but for my taste generally) i would take all the nested functions out of sieObjektLista, which allows you easily to test each (sub) parser function in isolation. you debug that in f# interactive. in general, nested functions avoid polluting the namespace but make code maintenance much harder (cannot run them in isolation anymore), so generally its better to avoid them unless good reasons are in their favor.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I wanted to keep the module interface fairly clean, but I think you are right. It makes it easier to debug etc if all parser functions can be accessed even if they're just used internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to consume too many spaces.

Look: `pdimObj` is a `pdim`, followed by some spaces, followed by `pobj`, which is itself a `pnum` followed by some spaces. So if you look at the first part of the input:

```
{ 53735        7785  86231   36732         }
  \___/\______/\__/\/
    ^      ^    ^   ^
    |      |    |   |
   pnum    |    |   |
    ^   spaces1 |   |
    |           |   ws
   pdim        pnum  ^
     ^          ^    |
     |          \    /
     |           \  /
     |            \/
      \          pobj
       \          /
        \________/
            ^
            |
          pdimObj
```

One can clearly see from here that `pdimObj` consumes everything up to `86231`, including the space just before it. And therefore, when `sepBy` inside `pdimObjs` looks for the next separator (which is `spaces1`), it can't find any. So it fails.

The smallest way to fix this is to make `pdimObjs` use `many` instead of `sepBy`: since `pobj` already consumes trailing spaces, there is no need to also consume them in `sepBy`:

```
let pdimObjs = many pdimObj
```

But a cleaner way, in my opinion, would be to remove `ws` from `pobj`, because, intuitively, trailing spaces aren't part of the number representing your object (whatever that is), and instead handle possible trailing spaces in `pdimObjs` via `sepEndBy`:

```
let pobj = pnum |>> fun x ->
    let on: ObjektNummer = int x.String
    on
...
let pdimObjs = sepEndBy pdimObj spaces1
```

Comment: That works great for valid input. Any suggestion on how to make the `(validList <|> invalidList)` use the invalidList if the validList fails? Currently it seems to expect a `dimOrObj` or a  `}`. But I would like it to use the invalidList parser function basically as a fallback.

Comment: Managed to figure it out by using `attempt` and some other minor adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is in `pdimObjs`. The `sepBy` parser fails because the separator spaces following each number have already been consumed by `pobj`, so `spaces1` cannot succeed. Instead, I suggest you try this:

```
let pdimObjs = many pdimObj
```

Which gives the following result on your test input:

```
Success: Ok [(53735, 7785); (86231, 36732)]
```

Comment: There is no need for `spaces`, they're already consumed in `pobj`.

Comment: Good point. Whitespace management in FParsec can be tricky.